# ¿Como usar SELECT2 de ajax para buscar por numero?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

estoy trabajando en una aplicacion y en mi aplicacion tengo un SELECT2 de ajax, el tema es que en mi selec solo busca por letras, pero me gustaria que busacara tambien por numeros, por ejemplo tengo en mi registro personas, que tiene un nombre y una cedula, me gustaria que ese Select buscara no solamente por el nombre sino que tambien por la cedula, como podia hacer?

Codigo en el html:

```
 <select name="estudiante" id="estudiante" class="form-control estudiante" required style="width: 100%;">
```

Codigo de mi Select2:

```
 $('.estudiante').select2({
        placeholder: 'Buscar Persona',
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: {
            url: base_url + 'Estudiantes/buscarEstudiante',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    est: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

Codigo de la funcion buscar:

```
 public function buscarEstudiante()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['est'])) {
            $valor = $_GET['est'];
            $data = $this->model->buscarEstudiante($valor);
            echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            die();
        }
    }
```

Codigo del BuscarEstudiantes:

```
public function buscarEditorial($valor)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id, editorial AS text FROM editorial WHERE editorial LIKE '%" . $valor . "%'  AND estado = 1 LIMIT 10";
        $data = $this->selectAll($sql);
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Omitiste la sección más importante: el código de tu modelo buscarEstudiante($termino), pero básicamente se trata de hacer una query sobre dos columnas: select * from persona where nombre like 'termino%' or cedula like 'termino%'. Suponiendo que tu modelo tenga las columnas nombre y cédula.

Comment: @Francisco disculpa, ya agrege el MSQL que Faltaba

Comment: Como indica @Francisco , edita tu query para que compare con cualquiera de las 2 columnas

Answer (score 0):

Primero, tu pregunta inicial es acerca de obtener personas (estudiantes) y la query que planteas al final trata de obtener editoriales. En cualquier caso se entiende tu duda y explico tu planteamiento inicial: *Obtener todos los estudiantes cuyo nombre o cedula coincida con el término de búsqueda*

```
SELECT * FROM estudiante WHERE estudiante.nombre LIKE '%termino%' OR estudiante.cedula LIKE '%termino%'
```

Ojo con el comdín `'%'` "rodeando" la variable `termino`; en este caso provoca que arroje todos los registros de la tabla estudiante que contengan en el nombre o en la cédula el término a buscar, independientemente de su posición dentro del valor de la columna.

Tal vez en tu caso te sea factible emplear otras variantes como obtener todos los estudiantes *cuyo nombre comience con termino o su cedula comience con termino*:

```
...estudiante.nombre LIKE 'termino%' OR estudiante.cedula LIKE 'termino%'
```

Y por último y no menos importante tener presente: **escapar todas las variables pasadas a la query**

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, @Francisco sabes que no me funciona aun lo del SQL, me muestra si la busqueda por numeros pero no por nombres mira hize esto: $sql = "SELECT id, titulo, codigolibro AS text FROM libro WHERE titulo LIKE '%" . $valor . "%' OR codigolibro LIKE '%" . $valor . "%' AND estado = 1 LIMIT 10 "; Este es un ejemplo con Libros

Comment: Aparte que lo que necesito es que cuando se selecione el codigo del libro me muestre su titulo no el codigo del libro